# building a Bigcommerce app, I'm getting Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bigcommerce

I am trying to build a Ruby on Rails application for Bigcommerce. They don't have a RoR hello world app, but they have a hello world sinatra app. I am trying to get that one up and running so I can figure out how that works and then get one working with Rails.

I clone the repo (https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-ruby-sinatra) and follow the instructions verbatim, however I am getting an `Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails` error in terminal, and a screen that shows "SSL protocol error" within Bigcommerce's iFrame (using chrome).

I don't know how to trace this error - it may not even be my fault, maybe requirements on Bigcommerce's side have changed and just haven't updated their hello world app. Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate installed?

Comment: @developerscott no - nowhere in the instructions did it tell me I needed one. But I got one, and now it works.

Comment: It actually does mention several places throughout the documentation that it needs to be served over TLS.

Comment: @developerscott nowhere on the hello-world-app page does it mention SSL or TLS. it says 'You can get started in development by simply running foreman start to run it locally, and then use localhost in your URLs'

Comment: in the first paragraph of the homepage of the API documentation it says "All connections require authentication and are secured by TLS encryption." Not trying to be lame. Just pointing it out. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api

Comment: @developerscott I understand that. Any hello-world app is meant to get you from square-1 to working code. There isn't even a mention of it there. Even in their docs, they only mention ngrok in the webhooks section. They should mention it in the same paragraph you're referring to, and in the hello-world app instructions. Do you not agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I needed to create a self-signed SSL cert and boot my localhost server with it.

follow these instructions to do so:
http://www.railway.at/2013/02/12/using-ssl-in-your-local-rails-environment/

when it says "Simply add force_ssl to any controller you want to secure with SSL" you literally just put `force_ssl` in its own line, below `class YourController < ActionController`

in the railway.at instructions, it uses `localhost.key` and `localhost.cert` in the options whereas in the gist link it references, it generates `server.key` and `server.cert` files. also, `--ssl-verify` is outdated and doesn't work. so when I start my server from terminal, this is the command I used:

`thin start -p 5000 --ssl --ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file ~/.ssl/server.crt`

**UPDATED BETTER SOLUTION:**

Use https://ngrok.com/

it gives you a free https page that redirects to your localhost. It's randomly generated (you can pay $60/yr for a specific subdomain) but if you just never shut it off, even if you close your computer, it'll stay active. This way, you can use the https link as the callback url you give bigcommerce, and it will load the pages hosted on your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in Python but ran into the same problem.  One solution I have found that might help given you get an "SSL protocol error"

If you are using store-XXXXX.mybigcommerce.com it will cause an error because the name on the SSL certificate is for yourstore.com  not what is above.

I tried switching to just mystore.com but all it did was change from one kind of error to another.  There are ways to set whatever is doing you GET/POST requests to ignore that error in python, not sure the same for Ruby.  I have yet to try that option to see if it works.

Comment: see my updated answer if you're still having problems